# Spring custom annotation for this behavior

Tags: spring, ioc-container

I have code like this.

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Component("studentInfo")
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile("studentInfo")
public class CustomStudentInfo{
```

As you can see i have the component name and the same profile i mean i just want to set this class as a bean only when the profile is set and fact this is working but is kind annoying to type this on 2 lines my question is can i have this on a custom annotation i mean a annotation that help me just to write.

```
@CustomSpringAnnotation("studentInfo")
public class CustomStudentInfo{
```

Thanks and sorry if the question is plain.

Comment: the obstacle i see, when introducing a custom annotation, is, that you cannot pass your custom annotation's `value` ("studentInfo") to @Profile/@Component...same with a "base class", you could only go with "constant expressions" (which can also be (static) final fields)

Comment: Hi thanks can you provide some example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "incorporate" the spring annotations into a custom one like (source/proof: [SpringBootApplicaiton source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.java)):

```
package my.package.annotations;

@org.springframework.stereotype.Component("studentInfo") // needs "constant expression" here 
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile("studentInfo") // .. and here!
public @interface MyCustomSpringAnnotation { ...
    // but here you have a problem,
    // since you cannot pass (at least not to the above annotations,
    // ... but maybe dynamically *hack* into the spring context):
    String value() default ""; //?
}
```

...then you could use it like:

```
@MyCustomSpringAnnotation 
public class CustomStudentInfo { // ...
```

but with the fixed "studentInfo" it is no improvement (but the contrary).

---

The probably "most spring-like" and best solution (no stress with "too many annotations") is: To consume `"studentInfo"` from a "visible" (static) final variable (probably best in the affected class):

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Component(CustomStudentInfo.PROFILE_NAME)
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile(CustomStudentInfo.PROFILE_NAME)
public class CustomStudentInfo {

    public static final String PROFILE_NAME = "studentInfo";
    // ...
```